# LINQ check if rows fall in between dates with no gaps

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to write a query where it will only return the rows if the dates fall between a start and end date without having gaps.

Below would fail and return nothing:

```
Requested -----[---------------------------------]--------
In the DB ----------------[------]------------------------

Requested -----[---------------------------------]--------
In the DB --[----------------]----------------------------

Requested -----[---------------------------------]--------
In the DB --[----------------]---------[----------------->
```

Below would pass and return the rows from the database:

```
Requested -----[---------------------------------]--------
In the DB -----[---------------------------------]--------

Requested -----[---------------------------------]--------
In the DB --[------------------------------------------]--

Requested -----[---------------------------------]--------
In the DB --[----------------][---------------][--------]-
```

**EDIT**

Here's the POCO object of what the table will look like:

```
public class SubscriptionPeriod
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public int? MatchedSubscriptionPeriodId { get; set; }
    public SubscriptionPeriodStatuses Status { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public int? FillQty { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubscriptionStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SubscriptionEndDate { get; set; }
    public int? RenewQty { get; set; }
    public bool RollOverQty { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ProcessedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}

SubscriptionPeriods
    .Where(sp => sp.Subscription.UserId == userId && 
        sp.Subscription.ZoneId == zoneId && 
        sp.Subscription.Type == 2 && 
        sp.MatchedSubscriptionPeriodId == null && 
        sp.SubscriptionStartDate <= subscriptionEndDate &&
        sp.SubscriptionEndDate >= subscriptionStartDate &&
        (sp.Status == SubscriptionPeriodStatuses.Initalized || sp.Status == SubscriptionPeriodStatuses.Open))
    .Sum(s => (int?)s.Qty)
```

**NOTE:** When SubscriptionEndDate is `null` means the subscription lasts forever from the start date.

Comment: show how your classes/tables are defined.

Comment: If i understood you correctly, you just want to handle null value of SubscriptionEndDate. Am i correct?

Comment: @Naveen - That and if there are gaps then return nothing.